# Issue in nginx server when request goes first time "404 not found "?

Tags: nginx, https

when any new user try to hit my domain name "papa.fit" so it shows

> 404 not found

my site is running on https provided by letsencrypt and I think whenever first request comes, it goes for http and not for https. what can be the issue ?

**server block for papa.fit**

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

    server_name papa.fit, www.papa.fit;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    #listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/waev.in;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name papa.fit, www.papa.fit;
        include snippets/ssl-papa.fit.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }


}



# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running this configuration? Stop and restart nginx.

Comment: yes, I am using this configuration.

Comment: I am checking in access log of nginx and i got this  "64.233.173.153 - - [24/Feb/2017:14:36:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 206 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36""

Comment: https uses port 443. http uses port 80. `listen 80; listen [::]:80` might be wrong?

Comment: I changed it but still has same problem

Comment: I got the issue. whenever a new device try to request first time , the request redirects to default block and not to papa.fit server block. but I don't know how to resolve this.can anybody ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name` is without comma between the names, try:

```
server_name papa.fit www.papa.fit;
```